# Restart a currently running step in a chain

Tags: oracle, plsql

I currently have a chain with over 500 steps in it running.

It seems to be running extremely slowly on one of the steps (if running at all).

I'd like to restart the chain at this step (it's the only thing currently running). I'd prefer to do this without dropping the chain (as restarting it this far in will be a pain) or killing the session.

I've read quite a bit of documentation and searched all over the internet for a really simple way to do this and I can't seem to find anything.

p.s. this is running in oracle/plsql.

Comment: is the chain currently stalled?

Comment: Not currently stalled that step is running.

Comment: Why you want to restart if step is slow? you will return to step again later, can you explain more?

Comment: I'm going to use gather stats on the table so the optimiser knows how to handle the query better. I have schema a, with a chain that calls a subchain. When I try stop_job('Schema.MasterJob.SubJob.Step); it says that it is an unknown object...